# Bluetooth android remote PC

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a project with android remote PC using Bluetooth to use android phone as a mouse or keyboard.

However the challenge is that PC don't install any server software, it just accepts the request to connect from android phone.

which library android support for this and what component in PC that smartphone send control signal to ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420353/android-client-server-application-via-bluetooth